# Emulating a HTTP Post Request in Python

Tags: php, python, http, post, request

I am trying to send a HTTP post request in a PHP page. I gave a try on both Java and Python (this was the first time I used Python) and I can say that both of them worked almost fine for me. Actually, they worked fine only for my test PHP page. For some reason, neither of them worked for my target PHP page.

In my opinion, two reasons that may cause the problem of unsuccessful post request could be:

1. a kind of redirection may happen
2. the server wants a proper cookie

Next, you will find the HTML code of the target page and the Python code that should be working.

HTML:

```
<form id="m713a0moduleform_2" method="post" action="http://www.X.Y/index.php?page=login" class="cms_form">
<input type="hidden" name="mact" value="FrontEndUsers,m713a0,do_login,1" />
<input type="hidden" name="m713a0returnid" value="794" />
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="794" />
<input type="hidden" name="m713a0form" value="login" />
<input type="text" class="cms_textfield" name="m713a0feu_input_username" id="m713a0feu_input_username" value="" size="10" maxlength="40" />
<input type="password" class="cms_password" name="m713a0feu_input_password" value="" size="10" maxlength="10" />
<input class="cms_submit" name="m713a0feu_btn_login" id="m713a0feu_btn_login" value="Sign in" type="submit" class="signin_button" />
</form>
```

Python:

```
import urllib
params = urllib.urlencode({"mact":"FrontEndUsers,m713a0,do_login,1","m713a0returnid":"18","page":"18","m713a0form":"login","m713a0feu_input_username":"Z","m713a0feu_input_password":"W","m713a0feu_btn_login":"Sign in"})
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.X.Y/index.php?page=login", params)
print f.read()
```

I receive the following error. Any ideas?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/X/Y/Z/NewPythonProject2/src/newpythonproject2.py", line 34, in 
    from paste.proxy import TransparentProxy
ImportError: No module named paste
```

Comment: http://diveintopython.org/http_web_services/redirects.html describes how to handle redirects.

Answer (score 1):

I use [paste.proxy.TransparentProxy](http://pythonpaste.org/modules/proxy.html#paste.proxy.TransparentProxy) and [webob.Request](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/reference.html#id1) ...

You need to install the libraries

```
easy_install webob webtest paste
```

or

```
pip install webob webtest paste
```

then in a script...

```
from paste.proxy import TransparentProxy
from webob import Request
proxy_app = TransparentProxy()    
request = Request.blank("http://pathto/your_file.php", POST=dict(field_a=value_a,field_b=value_b))

response = request.get_response(proxy_app)
```

if you need to do anything fancier like maintain cookies across requests like passing cookies back you could use [WebTest](http://pythonpaste.org/webtest/#testapp) and you would only a few changes

```
from paste.proxy import TransparentProxy
from webtest import TestApp
app = TestApp(TransparentProxy())    
app.post("http://pathto/your_file.php", dict(field_a=value_a,field_b=value_b))
```

Comment: there's libraries you have to install

easy_install paste webob webtest

Comment: Hi Tom! And thank you very much for your quick edit, but I still not getting it! These are my first lines in Python and that's why I can't figure out what to do even if I tried hard searching on the net... Can you please provide me with some hints about how to install all these libraries, given that I am running Ubuntu 10.10 and I am using NetBeans IDE 6.9.1? Much appreciate for your help! Eualin.

Comment: @eualin you've picked a somewhat sophisticated problem by which to get familiar with python. :) It would probably do you some good to get familiar with how to do things like install libraries in python. Because it is the libraries that make the language nowadays. I would install virtualenv if I were you. 

http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/

then you can play around with all kinds of libs and not wreck your system python